# Java EditText not validating correctly

Tags: java, android

Can someone help with this? My EditText is not empty but the toast still shows up. My app require users to select Date and Time, then select 1 item on the listview to proceed. A dialog will pop out after that. However for some reason, even though my edittext isn't empty, it still won't allow me to continue. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong, I mean the code is just that simple, nothing complicate.

```
final String date = textDate1.getText().toString().trim();
    final String time = textTime1.getText().toString().trim();

listViewHistory.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    final Team team = teams.get(i);

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(date)){
        Toast.makeText(RecreateActivity.this,"Please choose a date.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(time)){
        Toast.makeText(RecreateActivity.this,"Please choose a time.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

//the rest of the code

final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecreateActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirm_layout, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    final Button buttonYes2 = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonYes2);
    final Button buttonNo2 = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonNo2);
    //final Team team = teams.get();

    final AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
    b.show();

    buttonYes2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            databaseMembers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    final ArrayList<String> CheckList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (DataSnapshot check : dataSnapshot.child("teams").getChildren()) {
                        CheckList.add(check.getKey());
                    }
                    if (CheckList.contains(team.getTeamName())) {
                        Toast.makeText(RecreateActivity.this, "Team already exist.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    databaseMembers.child("History").child(team.getTeamName()).child("date").setValue(date);
                    databaseMembers.child("History").child(team.getTeamName()).child("time").setValue(time);

                    for (DataSnapshot history : dataSnapshot.child("History").child(encodedEmailAddress).getChildren()) {
                        String key = history.getKey();
                        if (key.equals(team.getTeamName())) {
                            teams.clear();
                            Team team = history.getValue(Team.class);
                            teams.add(team);
                            databaseTeams.child(team.getTeamName()).setValue(team);
                        }
                        if (key.equals("teamMember")) {
                            for (DataSnapshot members : dataSnapshot.child("History").child(encodedEmailAddress).child("teamMember").getChildren()) {
                                String key2 = members.getKey();
                                String value = members.getValue(String.class);
                                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                                map.put(key2, value);

                                databaseMembers.child("members").child(team.getTeamName()).child("teamMember").updateChildren(map);
                                b.dismiss();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    Toast.makeText(RecreateActivity.this, "Team created.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(RecreateActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Previous Team"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select new Date/Time and tap on the Team."
    android:textAlignment="center"/>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewHistory"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Members:"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textDate1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Select Date..."
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textTime1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Select Time..."
    android:layout_below="@+id/textDate"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAddHistory"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Create Team"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    tools:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: paste your complete code

Comment: just check it by length of the string in edittext is greater than zero

Comment: where you assigning that value only once?  you can need updated value, so get it in onItemClick may be you are setting value at the time of initialize

Comment: All right I got it, thanks everyone for the quick reply. I didn't knew putting those outside or inside will affect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting string from `EditText` only once - before setting `OnItemClickListener`. You need to get string inside the listener.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    final Team team = teams.get(i);
    final String date = textDate1.getText().toString().trim();
    final String time = textTime1.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(date)){
        Toast.makeText(RecreateActivity.this,"Please choose a date.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(time)){
        Toast.makeText(RecreateActivity.this,"Please choose a time.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your field is initialized only once. I don't know the context, this may be actually what you want, but then it doesn't make any sense to validate it every time, those fields have the same value every time the listener code is run. Try to add the code to get date and time in the listener itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is setting [date] and [time] *outside* of the onClickListener.  When the user clicks the button, your code isn't resetting the variables.  I'd evaluate the EditText directly from your onClickListener code:

```
listViewHistory.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    final Team team = teams.get(i);

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(textDate1.getText().toString().trim())){
        Toast.makeText(RecreateActivity.this,"Please choose a date.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(textTime1.getText().toString().trim())){
        Toast.makeText(RecreateActivity.this,"Please choose a time.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting date value of edittext inside the click listener.

Answer (score 0):

```
listViewHistory.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        final Team team = teams.get(i);
    final String date = textDate1.getText().toString().trim();
        final String time = textTime1.getText().toString().trim();

        if(date.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(RecreateActivity.this,"Please choose a date.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if(time.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(RecreateActivity.this,"Please choose a time.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
```